# navsat_transform_node imu topic data mapping problem

Tags: gazebo, robot-localization, topic, ros-noetic, navsat-transform-node

I ran into the problem of mapping the **/imu/data** topic of the **navsat_transform_node** node in the **robot_localization** package. the node has a very strange behavior - when mapping imu data to the **/front_rs_d455_camera/imu** topic, the topic does not exist.

```
<!-- navsat_transform -->
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find four_ws_robot_software)/config/robot_localization/navsat_transform.yaml" />
    <!-- inputs -->
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered/global"/>
    <remap from="gps/fix" to="bottom_gps_sensor/fix"/>
    <remap from="imu/data" to="front_rs_d455_camera/imu"/>
    <!-- outputs -->
    <remap from="odometry/gps" to="odometry/gps"/>
    <remap from="gps/filtered" to="gps/filtered"/>
</node>
```

**rodnode info** provides the following information

```
rosnode info navsat_transform_node     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/navsat_transform_node]
Publications: 
 * /gps/filtered [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix]
 * /odometry/gps [nav_msgs/Odometry]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /tf_static [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]

Subscriptions: 
 * /bottom_gps_sensor/fix [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix]
 * /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock]
 * /odometry/filtered/global [nav_msgs/Odometry]
 * /tf [tf/tfMessage]
 * /tf_static [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
```

moreover, I am sure that the data type in the topic **/front_rs_d455_camera/imu** is correct, it coincides with the default topic data type (I removed the remap line and saw that the node subscribes to the topic **/imu/data**)

```
rostopic info /imu/data                          
Type: sensor_msgs/Imu

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /navsat_transform_node (http://GP-76:36515/)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rostopic info /front_rs_d455_camera/imu        
Type: sensor_msgs/Imu

Publishers: 
 * /gazebo (http://GP-76:34583/)

Subscribers: 
 * /ekf_local (http://GP-76:45419/)
 * /ekf_global (http://GP-76:43401/)
 * /rviz (http://GP-76:32939/)
```

Please tell me what can be done to make the system work? I will be very grateful for any comments!!

P.S. I found the following code in the source code of the node

```
nh_priv.param("use_odometry_yaw", use_odometry_yaw_, false);
nh_priv.param("wait_for_datum", use_manual_datum_, false);
...
if (!use_odometry_yaw_ && !use_manual_datum_)
    {
      imu_sub_ = nh.subscribe("imu/data", 1, &NavSatTransform::imuCallback, this);
    }
```

but I use the following config

```
zero_altitude: true
publish_filtered_gps: true
use_odometry_yaw: false
wait_for_datum: false
broadcast_utm_transform: true
broadcast_utm_transform_as_parent_frame: true
transform_timeout: 0
```

therefore, a topic should be created for publication in the **navsat_transform_node** node

Comment: Why is the node named "navsat_transform" is one place, and "navsat_transform_node" in the other?

Comment: @Mike973, thank you for your attention! yes, you are right, while I was composing the question, I was experimenting with the names of nodes and topics, so in the output of the `rostopic info /imu/data` command you could see a different node name. but now I'm sure I did everything right, because the `rosnode info navsat_transform_node` command has the following output -
`
Node [/navsat_transform_node]
Subscriptions: 
 * /bottom_gps_sensor/fix [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix]
 * /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock]
 * /odometry/filtered/global [nav_msgs/Odometry]
`

Comment: Can you upload your project files from catkin_ws/src/ to github, then give us a url?

Comment: Do your other remappings work?